# SQL Server 2014 Express not working

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2014-express

I am new to database. Tried to add new item in Visual Studio 2010 in Windows 8 i.e. "SQL Server Database" and getting the following error

> A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while
>   establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or
>   was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that
>   SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: SQL
>   Network Interfaces, error: 26 - Error Locating Server/Instance
>   Specified)

Then I installed SQL Server 2014 Express... still I am getting the same error

I tried to start SQL Server (`SQLEXPRESS`) from SQL Server Configuration Manager then I get this error:

> "The request failed or the service did not respond in timely fashion.
>   Consult the event log or other appropriate error logs for details"

I am very new to using SQL Server, please provide step by step solution.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Got the same error when trying to run from Services.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please check the mssql server status in control panel > administrative tools > services and try to start it from there